# How to prevent a dialog (alert) from closing when you touch outside or press back using Anko

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm ussing kotlin and anko for creating an alert/dialog (code below), but when you tap outside or press back it closes.

Here is the code

```
alert("TITLE") {
    title("Text")
    positiveButton("Ok") { action() }
}.show()
```

Here is how the solution will be in java (without ussing anko too)

```
dialog.setCancelable(false); // for prevent on back pressed
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); // for prevent on touching outside
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this using kotlin and anko? Thanks :)

Comment: please check my solution and let me know in case of concern..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`Anko`** library of **`kotlin`**, provides the functionality to prevent dialog to close when press outside the dialog.. There is **`cancellable(BOOLEAN)`** method of **`alert`** to provide this functionality.

I have used the below lines of code to stop alert dialog to close.

```
alert("Testing alerts") {
                title("Alert")
                cancellable(false)  ////SET TRUE/FALSE ACCORDING TO URS REQUIREMENT
                positiveButton {
                   ///PERFORM ANY TASK HERE
                    dismiss()
                }
                negativeButton {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }.show()
```

Comment: I'll be looking at this now :)!

Comment: @QUIQUELHAPPY happy to help u bro :)

Comment: @Parker hmmm... Should be working fine, did you manage to fix that or...?

Comment: this doesn't work for me. "cancellable(false)" doesn't lite up in Android Studio 3 as being available (get an "Unresolved reference: cancellable" error) on the Anko alert object

Comment: @ajonno I have given the solution about 10 months ago..It was working at that time..Currently m not working on kotlin..so i am not able to help u..Thanks